# Cannot open PDF files in AIR app on Mac OS Yosemite error 3204

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, pdf, air, flash-builder

I am having trouble opening a PDF file in adobe air application on Mac OS 10.10.4. I already installed adobe reader 11.0.12 and air on mac.
I also traced HTMLLoader.pdfCapatibility, which returns 3204 (An error was returned by the OS when trying to load the Adobe Reader or Acrobat application or one of its necessary libraries.) .
I am showing you some sample code to you.

```
if(HTMLLoader.pdfCapability == HTMLPDFCapability.STATUS_OK)
  {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(tempFile.url);
            pdf.load(request);
            var ui:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            ui.addChild(pdf)
            container.addChild(ui);
}
  else
{
  trace("PDF cannot be displayed. Error code:",HTMLLoader.pdfCapability);
  }
```

It shows the output :  PDF cannot be displayed. Error code: 3204
Please let me know if anyone have any ideas.

The same code works well on Mac updated from Mac 10.9 to 10.10!

Best regards

Comment: Did you try with StageWebView?

Comment: Thanks for idea. But, result is similar. PDF cannot be displayed, screen is black!

Comment: in both StageWebView modes?

Comment: Which version of Air? Flex? I am assuming that the PDF you are using  opens fine on the Mac outside of Air/Flash... also assuming Adobe Reader reader is installed and working and can view the PDF (not OS-X Preview, but Adobe Reader). As a 3204 is from the OS, something is failing in the Acrobat Reader loading or one of its libraries. Does the PDF have any 'special' embedded content, password locked? embedded fonts that do not exist? etc....

Comment: PDF display fine outside AIR application. I try with Adobe reader 11.0.12 and Apperçu. I work with sdk 4.7 and Adobe AIR 18. PDF is very basic no embedded content, no password… Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Error 3204 usually indicates a Adobe Reader problem.

- Is Adobe Reader installed?

  - this is also exposed as an 3201 error but a corrupt or a partial de-install
  - can allow the Reader check to pass, and then fail as a 3204.
- Does Adobe Reader launch fine?

  - No issues reported in OS-X's Console?
- Can you view the PDF? (in Reader not OS-X's Preview)

Review the PDF to determine if it has embedded resources that need to be loaded by Adobe Reader and might be missing and causing a shared library to fail:

- 'special' embedded content
- videos that do not play, missing codecs, etc..
- password locked?
- embedded fonts that do not exist?
- etc....

Comment: Adobe reader 11.0.12 installed and woks fine. PDF Files are very basic! Only with StageWebView,  those messages appear "The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.2 instead of 10.10.2. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number."  and "The function 'CGFontSetShouldUseMulticache' is obsolete". Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Indeed, Adobe Reader 11.0.12 seems to be version number of Adobe Reader DC. 
Today, I downloaded on https://get.adobe.com/fr/reader/otherversions/, Adobe Reader 11.0 and now all works well!!!